# Python Add an Item to an Array

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array

I have an ndarray that looks like this:

```
In  [1]: a
Out [1]: array(['x','y'], dtype=object)
```

Now I wanted to append a "z" to the end of it:

```
In  [2]: print([a,'z'])
[array(['x','y'],dtype=object), 'z']
```

Instead, what I want is:

```
['x','y','z']
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it using [numpy.append](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['x','y'])

b = np.append(a,['z'])

In [8]:b
Out[8]: array(['x', 'y', 'z'], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.append`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['x', 'y'])

np.append(a, 'z')
# array(['x', 'y', 'z'], 
#       dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to [append](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) (since you can use it for several iterables; check for example: [PEP3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)) you can use the "unpacking" symbol to do it:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['x','y'], dtype=object)
b = np.array([*a, "z"])
print(*a, "z")
print(b)
```

The result is this:

```
x y z
['x' 'y' 'z']
```